# Is there a way to add the country name after the woocommerce review

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, comments, review, country

i have created a store with Wordpress+ woocommerece, it's an international store, we ship worldwide, and i want to let our customers to leave the reviews for products, and my question is how to display the country name for all the reviews, maybe after their name?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8oK4.png)

I now use the profile builder to for collecting customers, so i can use the "pb_country" to get their country name, I know it might be possible to add some code to my subtheme, but unfortunately I don't know how to write that code.

If possible, for comments from customers who have placed an order, I would like to use the country of their shipping address, and for customers who have not placed an order, I would like to use the country they chose when they registered.

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: depends on where you want to get user meta you can go with get_comment_author_link() or comment_author() or other.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. You should consider reading [ask] and rewriting your question to include some coding you've tried to show that you have put in a little effort before you came here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that the WooCommerce review form is a modified WordPress comment form. Under the hood, WooCommerce uses the comment_form() function.

If you want to add a country name(custom field) at the beginning of the review form (before the rating field and after the authorization notice for the anonymous users), you’ll have to use two different hooks for the same field. That’s because WordPress handles the displaying of the form differently based on if a user is authorized or not.

To make sure that we modify only the WooCommerce review form, we’re going to use the is_product() conditional tag. And to make sure that we won’t duplicate the fields, we’re going to use the is_user_logged_in() function.

Here’s the code I wrote:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'render_pros_cons_fields_for_anonymous_users', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'comment_form_top', 'render_pros_cons_fields_for_authorized_users' );

function get_pros_cons_fields_html() {
ob_start();
?>

<div class="pcf-container">
    <div class="pcf-field-container">
        <label for="pros">Pros:</label>
        <input id="pros" name="pros" type="text">
    </div>
    
    <div class="pcf-field-container">
        <label for="cons">Cons:</label>
        <input id="cons" name="cons" type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}

function render_pros_cons_fields_for_authorized_users() {
if ( ! is_product() || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return;
}

echo get_pros_cons_fields_html();
}

function render_pros_cons_fields_for_anonymous_users( $defaults ) {
if ( ! is_product() || is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return;
}

$defaults['comment_notes_before'] .= get_pros_cons_fields_html();

return $defaults;
}
```